# Newly created Objects are overriding another Objects variables

Tags: java, constructor

When I create two Function objects, the valuesin the first get overwritten with the values assigned to the second object.

What am I misunderstanding about Java object creation?

```
public class Function { 

private static double coefficient;
private static int startX;
private static int endX;
private static int exponent;


protected Function(double coefficient, int startX, int endX, int exponent) {
    this.coefficient = coefficient;
    this.startX = startX;
    this.endX = endX;
    this.exponent = exponent;

  }  

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Function func1 = new Function(2, 1, 2, 2); 

    Function func2 = new Function(0,1,2,1/3);

    // now func1 properties are the same as func2
      } 
   }
}
```

Comment: Why, you are making the data fields static?

Comment: I am referencing them in methods further in the Function class. If i remove static, I get the error: "cannot make a static reference to the non-static field"

Comment: @theActuary:  you can always refer fields in function of same class without being static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code to the below

```
public class Function { 

private double coefficient;
private int startX;
private int endX;
private int exponent;


protected Function(double coefficient, int startX, int endX, int exponent) {
    this.coefficient = coefficient;
    this.startX = startX;
    this.endX = endX;
    this.exponent = exponent;

  }  

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Function func1 = new Function(2, 1, 2, 2); 

    Function func2 = new Function(0,1,2,1/3);

    // now func1 properties are the same as func2
      } 
   }
}
```

The code you have done , you are making `static` variables which are only created once for the application. So, every time it overrides the value.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are common to all objects, thus you are getting same value for both of objects. Remove the `static` keyword from class fields.

For ex.

```
private double coefficient;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your objects **seem** to have the same values because your attributes are `static`, they are attached to the *class*, not the *objects*.

In general, an object constructor should not manipulate `static` member variables.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your fields as `static`, so they are "shared" by all instances of `Function`. This is by definition.

Instead, just remove the `static` modifier and it will work fine. You can access non static members inside all methods of the class, no problem with that !

**EDIT** : same goes for `static` methods, just remove the `static` modifier if they need to work on non static members.

Answer (score 0):

**coefficient**, **startX**, **endX** and **exponent** all the fields of your class are static. And static variables are class variables that means it is shared by all the instances of your class **Function**

That is the reason it shows the most recent value of the data fields.

To modify your code simply remove the static keyword from all your data fields which will make them as instance variable and then every instance of your class will have its own copy of **coefficient**, **startX**, **endX** and **exponent**